# C++ thousand separator doesn't work for double

Tags: c++

Trying to format some values with thousand separator in C++,

Here is the code,

```
double value = 123456789.123456789; 

std::ostringstream stream1; 
stream1.imbue(std::locale(""));
stream1.precision(2);
stream1<<std::fixed;

stream1 << value;   

const std::string stdString = stream1.str();
const char* cStr = stdString.c_str();
std::cout << cStr << std::endl;
```

This works fine for long value but not for double. Am I missing something here?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Your example worked perfectly for me -- g++ 4.4.3 (I know, I need to update my compiler).

Comment: @FredLarson You know there are tons of options for online compilers these days, especially if you just want to test something on a more recent version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916000/online-c-compiler-and-evaluator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your default may not include the comma but you should be able to force the comma by creating your own [numpunct](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/numpunct) like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>

class commaPunct : public std::numpunct<char>
{
  protected:
     virtual std::string do_grouping() const
    {
        return "\03";
    }

    virtual char do_thousands_sep() const
    {
        return ',';
    }
};

int main()
{
   double value = 123456789.123456789; 

   std::ostringstream stream1; 
   std::locale comma(std::locale(), new commaPunct());
   stream1.imbue(comma);

   stream1.precision(2);
   stream1<<std::fixed;

   stream1 << value;   

   const std::string stdString = stream1.str();
   const char* cStr = stdString.c_str();
   std::cout << cStr << std::endl;
}
```

Your example also did not work for me but using this code I was able to obtain commas. Also you can see [do_thousands_sep](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/numpunct/thousands_sep) .

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Any idea why it is ok for 'long' but not for 'double'?

Comment: @iraSenthil No, I am not sure why, as far as I know the behavior should be consistent at least for the compilers I had access to it was. What compilers version and platform are you using? Did this solution solve your problem?

Comment: I am using compiler version 12, its pretty old app and using IDE MS VC++ 6

Comment: @iraSenthil Once you get that far back all bets are off, if you can use a more modern compiler that would be better, here is an old thread on online C++ compilers if you can't upgrade and want to try a more modern compiler: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916000/online-c-compiler-and-evaluator